# How to increase the wheel the size in rotating wheel in ios?

Tags: ios, rotation

[image]I am developing an iPad app in that am using rotating wheel. I used the code which is given in this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit. In this i have increased the rotating wheel frame size. I used the below code

```
SMRotaryWheel *wheel = [[SMRotaryWheel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)  
                                                andDelegate:self 
                                               withSections:8];

wheel.center = CGPointMake(400,300);
[self.view addSubview:wheel];
```

This increase the image size. Wheel for rotation is in the same size. I want to increase the wheel circle to bebig. I have used the below code to draw the wheel. Pls help me to do.

```
 - (void) drawWheel {
    container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

    CGFloat angleSize = 2*M_PI/numberOfSections;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment.png"]];

        im.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
        im.layer.position = CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2.0-container.frame.origin.x, 
                                        container.bounds.size.height/2.0-container.frame.origin.y); 
        im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize*i);
        im.alpha = minAlphavalue;
        im.tag = i;

        if (i == 0) {
            im.alpha = maxAlphavalue;
        }

        UIImageView *cloveImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120)];
        cloveImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i.png", i]];
        [im addSubview:cloveImage];

        [container addSubview:im];
    }

    container.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self addSubview:container];

    cloves = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfSections];

    UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    bg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    [self addSubview:bg];

    UIImageView *mask = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 58, 58)];
    mask.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"centerButton.png"] ;
    mask.center = self.center;
    mask.center = CGPointMake(mask.center.x, mask.center.y+3);
    [self addSubview:mask];

    if (numberOfSections % 2 == 0) {

        [self buildClovesEven];
    } else {

        [self buildClovesOdd];
    }

    [self.delegate wheelDidChangeValue:[self getCloveName:currentValue]]; 
}
```

I need to enlarge the grey colour circle till the outer blue circle.

Comment: you need to increase the rectangle size also and the image too.

Comment: not rectangle. wheel i need to increase. So in code i need to increase the container size. Frame of the container i need to set

Comment: @Umarajendran are you pointing about the blue coloured outer ring?

Comment: no that ring is increased. grey color segment i need to increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert but this is how I've done mine. bare in mind I've used a label but it resizes fine. hopefully, you can get some help from this

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
    UIImageView *im = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment.png"]];
    im.frame = CGRectMake( 0 ,0, self.frame.size.width / 2.2,  M_PI * (container.frame.size.width   / numberOfSections) );
    im.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
    im.layer.position = CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2.0-container.frame.origin.x,
                                    container.bounds.size.height/2.0-container.frame.origin.y);
    im.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleSize*i);
    im.tag = i;
    [container addSubview:im];
}
```

this now resizes the sections to the correct size,

you may have to play around with the values to get the desired effect.
the problem you will have is the curve of the original image, it causes clipping.
a better way will probably be to draw the image dynamically, but I'm still learning how to do this my self.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by incresing the size of the sector image. Now i got a big wheel. Wheel is based on the size of the image we used for sector.Thanks for all your help